# PHP __set and __get overloading in inheritance

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

I am implementing an OOP design using PHP. I wonder how PHP handles inheritance for its magic methods like __get and __set.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $property1;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == "property1")
        {
            // do some logic
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name == "property1")
        {
            // do some logic
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        result;
    }
}
```

Now for extending `Foo`:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $property2;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (($result = parent::__get($name)) !== null)
            return $result; // may be null
        if ($name == "property2")
        {
            // do some logic
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (($result = parent::__set($name, $value)) !== null)
            return $result; // may be null
        if ($name == "property2")
        {
            // do some logic
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

As PHP returns `null` as the result of a function with nothing to return... this may lead in ambiguity of whether the `parent::__get()` or `parent::__set()` returned null truely or returned with no value; and leads to overhead.

Now if PHP considers the `static::_get()` and `static::__set()` first and fall backs to the `parent` versions on failure, this could be simplified as:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $property2;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name = "property2")
        {
            // do some logic
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name = "property2")
        {
            // do some logic
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I can't test it on current implementation because the classes in context manipulates production, live database. Which is the correct implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: "the classes in context manipulates production, live database" -- consider setting up a development environment with a dummy database. Having only a production environment limits your development capabilities severely.

Comment: you seem to have bugs in code if ($name = "property2") - I assume you wanted to use if ($name === "property2")

Comment: Thank you @Elias! I managed to create a dummy for my purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Valter ! I have some typos in above code that is fixed now.

Comment: Or simply don't use magic getters/setters at all (other than to throw Exception possibly) and enforce proper use of the defined getter/setter functions.  After all the properties were made inaccessible for a reason right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use magic methods only as proxy methods. Your code will be much cleaner and you don't have to deal with problems caused by inheritance.

Simple example:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $property1;

    public function setProperty1($property1)
    {
        // do some logic
        $this->property1 = $property1;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProperty1()
    {
        // do some logic
        return $this->property1;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $method = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method();
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . ucfirst($name);
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $property2;

    public function setProperty2($property2)
    {
        // do some logic
        $this->property2 = $property2;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProperty2()
    {
        // do some logic
        return $this->property2;
    }
}
```

Example call:

```
$bar = new Bar;
$bar->property1 = 'foo';
$bar->property2 = 'bar';
var_dump($bar);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant! but I guess instead of `$this` I should provide method_exists with `static` to work for inheritance!

Comment: Of course if you go through the exercise of defining proper getter/setter functions then you have no need for the magic functions at all other than to allow a more lax access paradigm (i.e. `$object->property` instead of `$object->getProperty()`) by the caller.

Comment: @MikeBrant it can be more complex. There are times when the getter/setter methods are set as private or protected for packaging. That way, the proxy looks neat. Though the end user doesn't have direct access to call `$object->getProperty` abundantly, it can access it through trying to reach an inaccessible property by `$object->userFriendlyNameForProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create an Isolated environment and test both methods.

**Method 1**

```
class Foo
{
    protected $property1;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == "name")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Foo::__get('$name') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property1;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name == "name")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Foo::__set('$name', '$value') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property1 = $value;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $property2;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == "place")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Bar::__get('$name') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property2;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name == "place")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Bar::__set('$name', '$value') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property2 = $value;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }
}

$bar = new Bar;

$bar->name = 'Alice';
$bar->place = 'Wonderland';

echo "done that: '{$bar->name} in {$bar->place}'";
```

The above code results are:

```
been here @line(59) Bar::__set('place', 'Wonderland') 
been here @line(43) Bar::__get('place') 
done that: ' in Wonderland'
```

That is clearly not the answer.

**Method 2**

```
class Foo
{
    protected $property1;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == "name")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Foo::__get('$name') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property1;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name == "name")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Foo::__set('$name', '$value') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property1 = $value;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $property2;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (($result = parent::__get($name)) !== null)
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") parent::__get('$name') <br/>";
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        if ($name == "place")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Bar::__get('$name') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property2;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (($result = parent::__set($name, $value)) !== null)
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") parent::__set('$name', '$value') <br/>";
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        if ($name == "place")
        {
            echo "been here @line(" . __LINE__ . ") Bar::__set('$name', '$value') <br/>";
            $result = $this->property2 = $value;
            return $result; // may be null
        }
        return;
    }
}

$bar = new Bar;

$bar->name = 'Alice';
$bar->place = 'Wonderland';

echo "done that: '{$bar->name} in {$bar->place}'";
```

Which results in:

```
been here @line(22) Foo::__set('name', 'Alice') 
been here @line(54) parent::__set('name', 'Alice') 
been here @line(59) Bar::__set('place', 'Wonderland') 
been here @line(11) Foo::__get('name') 
been here @line(38) parent::__get('name') 
been here @line(43) Bar::__get('place') 
done that: 'Alice in Wonderland'
```

This is the correct answer for overloading __get and __set magic functions while dealing with inheritance, but this has overheads. It is a solution but is there any better solution?